# tibble with dummies::dummy.data.frame requires an extra step

Tags: r, tibble

I just discovered a strange interaction with the `tibble` and `dummies` package, both of which I rely heavily upon. See the following first code:

```
data.frame(year = c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(year = as.factor(year)) %>% 
  dummies::dummy.data.frame(., dummy.classes = "factor")
```

which correctly produces

```
  year2015 year2016 year2017 year2018
1        1        0        0        0
2        0        1        0        0
3        0        0        1        0
4        0        0        0        1
```

If we add `as.tibble()` to the pipe, so that

```
data.frame(year = c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(year = as.factor(year)) %>%
  as.tibble() %>% 
  dummies::dummy.data.frame(., dummy.classes = "factor")
```

it produces

```
  year
1 2015
2 2016
3 2017
4 2018
```

If we add another extra step of `dummy.data.frame` to the second code, so that

```
data.frame(year = c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(year = as.factor(year)) %>%
  as.tibble() %>% 
  dummies::dummy.data.frame(., dummy.classes = "factor") %>% 
  dummies::dummy.data.frame(., dummy.classes = "factor")
```

it again produces

```
  year2015 year2016 year2017 year2018
1        1        0        0        0
2        0        1        0        0
3        0        0        1        0
4        0        0        0        1
```

Can't quite figure out what's going on here, and didn't see an issue filed at GitHub. My workaround currently is add `as.data.frame()` to the pipe whenever I'm working with `dummies`, but just curious as to why I have to.

Comment: `df2 <- data.frame(year = c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(year = as.factor(year)) %>%
  as.tibble() ; dummy(df2$year)` seem to work. Not sure why can't I put it in the `dplyr` chain and do it in one go.

Comment: @RonakShah Yeah I forgot to write that one down---that too. Very strange, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Hmmm...yes! Pretty weird, not sure if we are missing something or that is a bug.

Comment: The documentation at `?dummy` suggests that `data 
an object such as a data.frame or matrix that has colnames` so I am assuming it expects only data frame or matrix to work. This works too, `data.frame(y = c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)) %>% 
  dummy("y", data = .)`

Comment: A `tibble` is not a `data.frame`.  Please check the code in the `dummy.data.frame` as to how it is subsetting the data.  `data[, nm]`  can return a vector if there is only a single column in `data.frame`, not in `tibble`